# Can third party node modules be imported into extensions?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I am attempting to develop a brackets.io extension and plan on using a third party npm library? Can I import it?

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    var ExtensionUtils  = brackets.getModule("utils/ExtensionUtils");
    var CommandManager = brackets.getModule("command/CommandManager");
    var Menus = brackets.getModule("command/Menus");
    var modulePath = ExtensionUtils.getModulePath(module);
    var thirdPartyLib = require('./node_modules/lib/lib.js'); // this is throwing an error!


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Brackets extensions run in the webkit side, not in the node side.

Take a look at this page:
https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Node-Process:-Overview-for-Developers